# flet: how to disable a button/checkbox on select/value change

Tags: mobile-development, flet

how to disable the checkbox after the first click

```
def strike_text(e, text):
    if e.control.value is True:
        text.style = Style.striked_text
        # e.control.enabled = False ?

ft.Checkbox(on_change=lambda e: self.strike_text(e, text))
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you need to modify your Checkbox to

```
ft.Checkbox(label="your text", on_change=disable_on_change)
```

then your handler can be...

```
def disable_on_change(e):
    e.control.enabled = False
    page.update()
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to change the text style of the label property, though, as I've never tried that.